# How to shuffle/randomize a bootstrap responsive grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Using this code I was trying to randomize my responsive grid which is a 5x3 Matrix. I end up getting errors with appending to a child but I edited my code. Basically, the end result I would like is this

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10 11 12
13 14 15
```

to

```
10 11 12
13 14 15
7 8 9
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

The Format grid is:

```
<div id="shuffle">
<div class="text-center">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div></div>
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div></div>
```

'The jQuery being used:

```
function shuffle(tbl) {
    var arr = tbl.find("div");

   console.log("Finding the arr Value " + arr + " !");
    for(
      var j, x, i = arr.length; i;
      j = parseInt(Math.random() * i),
      x = arr[--i], arr[i] = arr[j], arr[j] = x
    );

    var tmp;
    var rows = tbl.find(".col-sm-4").length
    console.log("finding the row value " + rows + " !");

    //var cols = tbl.find(".col-sm-4:first .row").length
   var cols = 3;
   console.log("finding the cols value " + cols + " !");


    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        tmp = tbl.find("col-sm-4").eq(i);
    console.log("finding the tmp value " + tmp + " ! ");
        tmp.html()
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++)

        tmp.append(arr[i*cols+j]);

    }       
}

jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
     shuffle(jQuery("#shuffle"));
});
```

'

The console log outputs

```
Finding the arr Value [object Object] !
xxx/:923 finding the row value 15 !
xxx/:927 finding the cols value 3 !
xxx/:932 finding the tmp value [object Object] !
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a fairly short version. It self calculates the number of items per row from first row.

After shuffling uses `slice()` to create new items collection per row

```
// array shuffle utility
function shuffle(o) {
  for (var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
  return o;
}


function shuffleRows($rows) {

  var $items = $rows.children(),
    num_cols = $rows.eq(0).children().length,
    numRows = $rows.length;

  shuffle($items);

  for (var i = 0, j = 0; i < $items.length; i += num_cols, j++) {
    $rows.eq(j).append($items.slice(i, i + num_cols + 1))
  }

}

shuffleRows($('#shuffle .row'))
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/BRo19Vkbrpi1O40BCCR0?p=preview)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You are just juggling rows here. You can do that using this manner instead of that messy jQuery function that you've written:

```
// get every row in a variable 
//[Note: Use other class if you have other rows than these]
var rowX = $('.row:nth-child(x)'); //here, x = 1 to 5

// remove the parent node html
$('.text-center').html('');

// append the rows one by one in whatever order you need
$('.text-center').append(rowX); //x = 1 to 5
```